# Sublime Text 2 increment numbers

Tags: numbers, sublimetext2, increment

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
    "Algeriet" :
    [
        {
            "name" : "Nyårsdagen",
            "date" : "2013-01-01",
            "ID" : "1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Mawlid En Nabaoui Echarif",
            "date" : "2013-01-24",
            "ID" : "2"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Första maj",
            "date" : "2013-05-01",
            "ID" : "3"
        },
       ...
     ]
```

Now I would like to begin incrementing the IDs from 0 instead of 1. How can I do this with Sublime Text 2? I have installed the [Text Pastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry#insert-nums) plugin but I'm not sure how to select the IDs in the text so that I can replace these values.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Solved it by doing these steps:

1. Do a find and replace for regex `"ID" : "\d+"` and replacing it with a string which I know does not exist anywhere in the file (I replaced it with `"ID" : "xyz"`
2. Make a multiple selection on `"ID" : "xyz"`
3. Using the [Text Pastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry) plugin "Number Sequence (\i)" on the multiple selection

Comment: Other option:
1. Select the text (only one occurrence): "ID" : "
2. Press ALT+F3 (command "find_all_under") to select all occurrences
3. Navigate to the first character (Right arrow) and select all IDs (CTRL+SHIFT+Right). Now you have all identifiers selected.

Answer (score 19):

You can use **[Increment Selection](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Increment%20Selection)**. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> over multiple selections of numbers.

You will need [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) first. All of this shouldn't take more than 30 seconds to install.

Steps:

1. Install **Package Control**.

   - Open Command Palette: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows/Unix) / <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac).
   - Type `Install Package Control` and click to install.
2. Install **Increment Selection** package.

   - Open Command Palette again.
   - Type `Package Control: Install Package`, click on it and wait a short period.
   - Type `Increment Selection` and click on it to install.
3. Select multiple numbers and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Windows/Unix) / <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Mac).

Result:

[image: invert-selection.gif]

---

#### Other examples

*Increment Selection* can also prefix numbers with leading zeroes, increment letters, increment by a step, generate line numbers and more.

```
   [1] text    [1] text    [1] ->  1| text  2| text  3|
   [a] text    [a] text    [a] ->  a| text  b| text  c|
  [01] text   [01] text   [01] -> 01| text 02| text 03|
[05,3] text [05,3] text [05,3] -> 05| text 08| text 11|
[5,-1] text [5,-1] text [5,-1] ->  5| text  4| text  3|

[#] line -> 1| line
[#] line -> 2| line
[#] line -> 3| line
[#] line -> 4| line
[#] line -> 5| line
```

Hint: `[]` stands for a selection, `|` stands for a caret.

Answer (score 7):

With the new [add-text-with-sequence feature of the Text Pastry plugin](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry/issues/20), it's even a step less:

1. Find all `"ID" : "\d+"` (with regex search activated)
2. In the *Text Pastry Command Line*, enter `as "ID" : "0"`

Comment: This is now better then accepted answer. It's simple & it works! Don't forget to add + in regex: `\d+` if you have numbers with more digits.

Comment: it's 2020/5/5, and this answer works for Text Pastry, ST3. I prefer this answer because I have to replace 1k+ selections.