# generate HTML gallery

Tags: html, generator, sublimetext3, magnific-popup

I am making gallery in HTML with Magnific Popup, I want to have 100 images, HTML markup have to looks like this

```
<a href="/img/gallery/mdd-2014/img00001.jpg" title="title">
    <img src="/img/gallery/mdd-2014/thmb/img00001.jpg" alt="alt">
</a>

...

<a href="/img/gallery/mdd-2014/img00100.jpg" title="Škôlka pod lesom - Nová Baňa">
    <img src="/img/gallery/mdd-2014/thmb/img00100.jpg" alt="Škôlka pod lesom - Nová Baňa">    
</a>
```

How can I do it with the simplest way in Sublime Text 3 if I need to create new `a > img` and increment `href` and `src` 100 times?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 2 increment numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198845/sublime-text-2-increment-numbers)

Comment: You should provide us any code where we can see what you tried so far to help you out. We won't write one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution with [Emmet package](http://emmet.io/blog/sublime-text-3/) for Sublime text!

```
(a[href="/img/gallery/nase-aktivity/img$$$$$.jpg" title="title"]>img[src="/img/gallery/nase-aktivity/thmb/img$$$$$.jpg" alt="alt"])*100
```