# How to automatically increment/add/renumber numbers in Sublime 3 over many related files in a continuos way?

Tags: regex, numbers, sublimetext3, increment

I need to increment/add/renumber numbers (BibTeX keys) selected using regex over several hundred TeX files, maintaining the sequence from one file to the next, when sorted in alphanumeric order.

Files:

```
latex-01.tex
latex-02.tex
latex-03.tex
etc
```

Each file containing something like,

```
Text ... [bibkey01a] ...
More text [bibkey02] ...
```

I know it is [easily possible to do it on one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829047/). I have found several other similar pages on stackoverflow and other forums, but all deal only with one file at a time.

I could open each file, increment/add/renumber the numbers using [TextPastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry) or [Sublime-Evaluate](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/Sublime-Evaluate) and *manually* carry over the proper value to the next file and repeat the procedure for all the files.

That is possible but a daunting task when one has several hundred related files that need to have value renumbered in a continuos related way. Also, it would be *quite easy to make a mistake and carry over the wrong number.*

How to automatically increment/add/renumber numbers in Sublime 3 over many related files in a continuos way?

Comment: Care to share why the downvote? Is this question unclear, or not useful? I did spend quite a bit of research before posting it. Please offer advice on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Sublime 3 + extensions is not able to do what I need at the moment.

Of course I can do it with a script. I believe Emacs can do it too, using [helm-swoop](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop) and [wgrep](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep), then, using a replace expression that [contains](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37898/) [elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519627/) [code](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7612/).